# Handling complex and large dependencies

Tags: bazel

**Problem**

I've been developing a game in C++ in my spare time and I've opted to use `Bazel` as my build tool since I have never had a ton of luck (or fun) working with `make` or `cmake`. I also have dependencies in other languages (`python` for some of the high level scripting). I'm using `glfw` for basic window handling and high level graphics support and that works well enough but now comes the problem. I'm uncertain on how I should handle dependencies like `glfw` in a `Bazel` world.

For some of my dependencies (like `gtest` and `fruit`) I can just reference them in my `WORKSPACE` file and `Bazel` handles them automagically but `glfw` hasn't adopted `Bazel`. So all of this leads me to ask, what should I do about dependencies that don't use `Bazel` inside a `Bazel` project?

**Current approach**

For many of the simpler dependencies I have, I simply created a `new_git_repository` entry in my `WORKSPACE` file and created a `BUILD` file for the library. This works great until you get to really complicated libraries like `glfw` that have a number of dependencies on their own.

When building `glfw` for a Linux machine running `X11` you now have a dependency on `X11` which would mean adding `X11` to my `Bazel` setup. `X11` Comes with its own set of dependencies (the `X11` libraries like `X11Cursor`) and so on.

`glfw` also tries to provide basic joystick support which is provided by default in Linux which is great! Except that this is provided by the kernel which means that the kernel is also a dependency of my project. Now I shouldn't need anything more than the kernel headers this still seems like a lot to bring in.

**Alternative Options**

The reason I took the approach I've taken so far is to make the dependencies required to spin up a machine that can successfully build my game very minimal. In theory they just need a C/C++ compiler, Java 8, and `Bazel` and they're off to the races. This is great since it also means I can create a `Docker` container that has `Bazel` installed and do CI/CD really easily.

I could sacrifice this ease and just say that you need to have libraries like `glfw` installed before attempting to compile the game but that brings the whole which version is installed and how is it all configured problem back up that `Bazel` is supposed to help solve.

Surely there is a simpler solution and I'm overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `glfw` project has no `BUILD` files, then you have the following options:

- Build `glfw` inside a `genrule`.

  If `glfw` supports some other build system like `make`, you could create a `genrule` that runs the tool. This approach has obvious drawbacks, like the not-to-be-underestimated impracticality of having to declare all inputs of that `genrule`, but it'd be the simplest way of Bazel'izing `glfw`.
- Pre-build `glfw.o` and check it into your source tree.

  You can create a `cc_library` rule for it, and put the `.o` file in the `srcs`. Even though this solution is the least flexible of all because you not only restrict the target platform to whatever the `.o` was built for, but also make it harder to reproduce the whole build, the benefits are sometimes worth the costs.

  I view this approach as a last resort. Even in Bazel's own source code there's one [`cc_library.srcs` that includes a raw object file](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/ab58a9244bfccbc80fc3970329a36ce6ee3d4006/src/main/cpp/BUILD#L87), because it was worth it, as the commit message of [`92caf38`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/92caf38a4ae74889391eefa9b7196804d8f2c948) explains.
- Require that `glfw` be installed.

  You already considered this option. Some people may prefer this to the other approaches.

Comment: I'll see if I can toss some scripts together to build `glfw` for the target platforms so at least I know the correct version can be installed and setup and go with the latter option for now. Thanks!